# Critical error when open lid of suspended thinkpad T14

Tags: suspend, thinkpad

Three days ago arrived my new Thinkpad T14 (AMD 7 Pro 5850U, DDR4, SSD M.2) with Windows 10.
I installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 beside Win10.
Partitions:
| EFI | Reserved Windows | Windows 10 | Restore Windows | Swap | / | home |

Kernel 5.15.0

Everything was fine, i close laptop lid, suspend ok but when open up and Ubuntu wake just crash with the follow messages:

EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p6): __ext4_find_entry:1612: inode #170139: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0

and

systemd-journald[403]: Failed to write entry (9 items, 326 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system

Just a blackscreen with this messages over and over. So the only option i have is to force power-off.

Doesn't matter how i suspend it,every time it wake up crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem origin and a solution.

After being hours looking ext4-fs errors the problem was 'Sleep State' mode.

In BIOS (Config > Power) there is a Sleep State setting by default on Windows (S0ix). This is not fully compatible with AMD processors so just changing to Linux (S3) the problem apparently could be solved. I said apparently because i moved to Debian 11, S0ix doesn't work fluid but at least SO doesn't crash forcing reboot.

Update: I Switched Sleep State from 'Windows' to 'Linux'. Sleep State working ok now on Debian 11. I had read that also works for Ubuntu 22.04 (https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/oj6s5v/t14_amd_does_changing_the_sleep_mode_to_linux/?sort=new).

Attention! pop up shows up before apply the change warning about to reinstall SO, the message said:
If Switch Sleep State to Linux, you must have a complete OS reinstall, Otherwise the system will be crash.

Do you really want to continue?

Select yes to Switch Sleep state to Linux.

Select No to discontinue the operation.

Well, this is not exactly true, doesn't happened to me and i found many others who haven't.